# Date translation using Free marker Syntax in Netsuite Advance PDF template

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I have a dilemma, we are a multi subsidiary company with subsidiaries in different countries/jurisdictions. All of which requires specific language and formatting for invoices/credit memos depending on the subsidiary. Currently our global date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and it is flowing correctly to the template, we want to show the Transaction and Due `(${record.trandate} +${record.duedate})`in `DD-Mon-YYYY (01-Jan-20015)` without changing the global date preference. AS per NS support if we change the date preference globally it may effect our existing forms and scripts.

Is there any Free Marker syntax that can translate the date format for those to fields from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `DD-Mon-YY`, any help is appreciated.

Sam Azad

Comment: Figured it out :
${record.trandate?string("dd-MMM-yyyy")}

Comment: Please answer and accept your question to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Also by adding <#setting date_format="dd-MMM-yyyy"/> in the head section also does the trick.